# Is this function differentiable at this point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y) = (1 - \cos(x^2 / y)) \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ for $y=0$. and define $f(x,0) = 0, x \in R$ Is this function diferenttiable at $(0,0) ?$. I did several computations but I am getting anywhere. Someone could help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define $f$ when $y=0$?

Comment: It is not differentiable since $\cos (x^2/y)$ is undefined for $y=0$.  Even if $f(0,0)$ is defined to make $f$ continuous at the origin.  the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ at $(0,0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The function $f(x,y)$ vanishes on the axes. Thus both partial derviatives of $f$ vanish at $(0,0).$ Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$ Then

$$f(x,y) = f(0,0) + 0\cdot x + 0\cdot y + o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}\ )$$

as $(x,y)\to (0,0).$ Check that this fails by looking at $f(x,x^2).$

Comment: The function vanishes on the axis $x=0$. But it is not defined on the axis $y=0$.

Comment: Yes it is, check again.

Comment: Ok ... The post was changed!

Comment: Right, I got to it after the dust had settled.